# KnockoutJS to show all lines in a model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a jquery/knockout app - which is for selecting availability for a hotel.

My JSon data is:

```
var sampleProductCategories = [{
"RoomName": null,
    "TypeName": "Type 1",
    "TypeID": 1,
    "TypeCount": 2,
    "Occs": [{
    "occdesc": "1 B&B",
        "curr": "£",
        "occdesc2": "1 B&B (£100.00)",
        "ratetocharge": 100.0000,
        "numOfOcc": 1,
        "RatesViewModel": null
}, {
    "occdesc": "1 Dinner",
        "curr": "£",
        "occdesc2": "1 Dinner (£100.00)",
        "ratetocharge": 100.0000,
        "numOfOcc": 1,
        "RatesViewModel": null
}]
}, {
"RoomName": null,
    "TypeName": "Type 2",
    "TypeID": 2,
    "TypeCount": 1,
    "Occs": [{
    "occdesc": "1 B&B",
        "curr": "£",
        "occdesc2": "1 B&B (£100.00)",
        "ratetocharge": 100.0000,
        "numOfOcc": 1,
        "RatesViewModel": null
}, {
    "occdesc": "1 Dinner",
        "curr": "£",
        "occdesc2": "1 Dinner (£100.00)",
        "ratetocharge": 100.0000,
        "numOfOcc": 1,
        "RatesViewModel": null
}]
}, {
"RoomName": null,
    "TypeName": "Type 3",
    "TypeID": 3,
    "TypeCount": 5,
    "Occs": [{
    "occdesc": "1 B&B",
        "curr": "£",
        "occdesc2": "1 B&B (£150.00)",
        "ratetocharge": 150.0000,
        "numOfOcc": 1,
        "RatesViewModel": null
}, {
    "occdesc": "1 Dinner",
        "curr": "£",
        "occdesc2": "1 Dinner (£180.00)",
        "ratetocharge": 180.0000,
        "numOfOcc": 1,
        "RatesViewModel": null
}]
}];
```

My HTML/Knockout is:

```
<div class='liveExample'>
<table width="100%" style="width:99%;" data-role="table" id="movietable2" class="ui-body-c ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive ui-table ui-table-columntoggle">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-bar-b">
            <th data-priority="1">Room Type</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Occupants</th>
            <th data-priority="4">Number reqd</th>
            <th data-priority="6"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: lines'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select data-bind='jqmOptionsdfd: sampleProductCategories, options: $root.RoomCategories, optionsText: "TypeName", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: category'></select>
            </td>
            <td data-bind="with: category">
                <select id="mine" data-bind='jqmOptionsdfd: sampleProductCategories, options: Occs, optionsText: "occdesc2", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: $parent.occupancy'></select>
            </td>
            <td class='quantity' data-bind="with: category">
                <select data-bind="visible: $parent.occupancy, options: ko.utils.range(0, TypeCount), value: $parent.quantiyt, jqmOptions:sampleProductCategories"></select>
            </td>
            <td> <a href="#" data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine' data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Remove</a>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;">
                 <h4 class='grandTotal'>
                Total value: <span data-bind='text: formatCurrency(grandTotal())'></span>
            </h4> 
                <button data-bind='click: addLine' data-icon="plus">Add another room</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me change this so that each "RoomName" is showing from the start.  So it shows:

Type 1....
Type 2....
Type 3....

...without having to click on Add Another Room?

There is a JSFiddle of it currently working here: http://jsfiddle.net/cGGvA/9/

Thanks for any help,

Mark

The jQuery for it is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
cart.RoomCategories(sampleProductCategories)


});

function formatCurrency(value) {
return "£" + value.toFixed(2);
}

ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
var max, min, observable, sValue, step;

min = 0;
max = 100;
sValue = 50;
step = 1;
observable = valueAccessor();
if (allBindingsAccessor().min != null) {
min = allBindingsAccessor().min;
}
if (allBindingsAccessor().max != null) {
  max = allBindingsAccessor().max;
}
if (allBindingsAccessor().slider() != null) {
  sValue = allBindingsAccessor().slider();
}
if (allBindingsAccessor().step != null) {
  step = allBindingsAccessor().step;
}
$(element).slider({
  value: sValue,
  min: min,
  max: max,
  step: step
}).on('slide', function(ev, ui) {
var slideValue;

slideValue = ui.value;
  alert(slideValue);
if (slideValue < min) {
  $(element).slider('value', min);
  return observable(min);
} else if (slideValue > max) {
  $(element).slider('value', max);
  return observable(max);
} else {
  return observable(slideValue);
}
}).on('stop', function(event, ui) {
if (ui.value < min) {
  $(element).slider('value', min);
  return observable(min);
} else if (ui.value > max) {
  $(element).slider('value', max);
  return observable(max);
}
});
return ko.bindingHandlers.validationCore.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
},
 update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {}
};

ko.bindingHandlers.jqmOptionsdfd = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
    $(element).selectmenu();

    $(element).selectmenu("refresh", true);
    //    alert("triggered");
}
};

ko.bindingHandlers.jqmOptions = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
        options: valueAccessor()
    }, context);
    $(element).selectmenu();
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
    $(element).selectmenu("refresh", true);
}
};

var CartLine = function () {
var self = this;
self.category = ko.observable();
self.categoryID = ko.observable();
self.occupancy = ko.observable();
self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
self.extraTowels = ko.observable(0);
$('.liveExample').trigger('create');
self.subtotal = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.occupancy() ? self.occupancy().ratetocharge * parseInt("0" + self.quantity(), 10) : 0;
});

// Whenever the category changes, reset the occupancy selection
self.category.subscribe(function () {
    self.occupancy(undefined);
});
};

var Cart = function () {
// Stores an array of lines, and from these, can work out the grandTotal
var self = this;
self.RoomCategories = ko.observableArray([]);
self.lines = ko.observableArray([new CartLine()]); // Put one line in by default
self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $.each(self.lines(), function () {
        total += this.subtotal()
    })
    return total;
});

// Operations
self.addLine = function () {
    self.lines.push(new CartLine());
    $('.liveExample').trigger('create');
};
self.removeLine = function (line) {
    self.lines.remove(line)
};

};


var cart = new Cart();
ko.applyBindings(cart);

function mtMob() {
  $('.liveExample').trigger('create');
};

function mtMob2() {
$('.liveExample').trigger('create');
};


function groupByTypeID(arr) {
var groupBy = {};
$.each(arr, function () {
    var currentCount = groupBy[this.TypeName] || 0;
    groupBy[this.TypeName] = currentCount + parseInt(this.TypeCount);
});
return groupBy;
}

function dump(arr, level) {
var dumped_text = "";
if (!level) level = 0;

//The padding given at the beginning of the line.
var level_padding = "";
for (var j = 0; j < level + 1; j++) level_padding += "    ";
if (typeof (arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects
    for (var item in arr) {
        var value = arr[item];
        if (typeof (value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
            dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
            dumped_text += dump(value, level + 1);
        } else {
            dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
        }
    }
} else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
    dumped_text = "===>" + arr + "<===(" + typeof (arr) + ")";
}
return dumped_text;
}
```

Comment: Just to be specific, your fiddle works in Chrome fine but not at all in IE11,  not event when you click Add. Perhaps check it with some different browsers and add your findings to the question?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the heads up.  I'm still wondering (even if I can get it to work in IE) how to display all of the data - and not just one line at a time.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: do you mean that you want to show 3 rows by default, one with each room type selected?

Comment: Hi Tanner - yes - so if there are three room types in the JSON, I want to show all 3 - if there are 5 - show all 5.  Thank you.

Comment: Surely its just a case of looping through your json and adding them to your lines array no?

Comment: Hi - possibly - but I'm not sure about Knockout.  Thanks, Mark